# Read mail from mail server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am creating a web application .. Through the application I will send mails to my clients(From e-mail address:admin@domain.com)...
If any client reply for my mail(To e-mail address:admin@domain.com) I want to read that details from admin@domain.com and insert into sql server database..

Please share your ideas to fix my problem...

Answer (score 0):

it depends on your scenario.. do you want to fetch the emails when pushing a button on a web page? or you want them to be automatically read and inserted in the sql db when they arrive in the mail?

at this [link text](http://dotnet.mvps.org/dotnet/faqs/?id=email&lang=en) you can find different solutions to fetch/send emails using C# from an email address (first scenario).

the second scenario would need some modifications to the email server to forward the email contents automatically to your application.